# React - passing state down

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, react-props

I am building a CV creator in React. I have a form, a preview component and their closest parent component is Main. What I want to achieve is that when a user is typing inside form fields, the preview fields on the right get automatically updated with data from form but I just can't get it to work. This is my first project in React, and I cannot use hooks or functional components. I know that I am doing something wrong, but cannot pinpoint what.

Main component

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Form from "./form/Form";
import Preview from "./formpreview/Preview";

class Main extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      firstName: "",
      lastName: "",
      title: "",
      address: "",
      phoneNum: "",
      email: "",
      description: "",
    };

    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
  };

  handleInputChange = (event) => {
    this.setState = {
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
    };
  };

  render() {
    const { firstName } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="main">
        <Form
          submitForm={this.handleSubmit}
          changeInput={this.handleInputChange}
          firstName={firstName} lastName={lastName} title= 
          {title} address={address} phoneNum={phoneNum}
          email={email} description={description}
        />
        <Preview onChange={this.handleInputChange} 
         firstName={firstName} lastName={lastName} title= 
          {title} address={address} phoneNum={phoneNum}
          email={email} description={description}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Form component

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Personal from './buildingblocks/PersonalInfo';
import Experience from './buildingblocks/Experience';
import Education from './buildingblocks/Education';
import Buttons from './buildingblocks/FormButtons';

class Form extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     this.state = {
       firstName: this.props.firstName,
       lastName: this.props.lastName,
       title: this.props.title,
       address: this.props.address,
       phoneNum: this.props.phoneNum,
       email: this.props.email,
       description: this.props.description
     }
   }

   submitForm = () => {
     this.props.submitForm()
   }

   changeInput = () => {
     this.props.changeInput()
   }

  
  render() {
    const {firstName, lastName, title, address, phoneNum, email, description} = this.state;
  
    return (
        <form className="cvForm" onSubmit={this.submitForm} onChange={this.changeInput}>
          <Personal firstName={firstName} lastName={lastName} title={title} address={address} phoneNum={phoneNum} email={email} description={description}/>

          <Experience />

          <Education />

          <Buttons />

        </form>
    );
  }
}

export default Form;
```

Preview Component

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Preview extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      firstName: this.props.firstName,
      lastName: this.props.lastName,
      title: this.props.title,
      address: this.props.address,
      phoneNum: this.props.phoneNum,
      email: this.props.email,
      description: this.props.description
    }
  }

  submitForm = () => {
    this.props.submitForm()
  }

  changeInput = () => {
    this.props.changeInput()
  }


  render() {
    const {firstName, lastName, title, address, phoneNum, email, description} = this.state;

    return (
      <div className="cvPreview">
        <div className="gridItem nameItem">
          <h1>{firstName} </h1>
          <h3>Data engineer</h3>
        </div>
       
...
    );
  }
}
```

I haven't included all of preview component because it is just elements. I know I am not doing this correctly, I am getting a TypeError "Cannot read property 'target' of undefined" and I am pretty sure I shouldn't be defining these props this many times, but after everything I have tried, this was my last shot. I am stuck, help.

Comment: Why can't you use functional components and React hooks? Stuck in older React version?

Comment: Part of the curriculum. I guess to get comfortable with class components first.

Comment: In your Form component, you have `this.props.changeInput()`. But that function is expecting the event as an argu ment. So you should have `changeInput = (event) => { this.props.changeInput(event) }` (though I'm not 100% sure the type of event that is fired when you attach the `onChange` directly to the `<form/>` element, so maybe print it out and see).

Comment: You might end up having a lot of deprecated components when they move class components out of newer versions of react...

Comment: @ChristianMoen AFAIK React has made no mention of removing classes from React, too many dependencies. Not in this [blog post](https://reactjs.org/blog/2019/02/06/react-v16.8.0.html) introducing hooks from Feb 6, 2019, or any since that I'm aware of. Do you have a citation?

Comment: Sure, Drew. There's no mention, but things can change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issues

### Main

1. `handleInputChange` the `this.setState` should be a function call.

   ```
   handleInputChange = (event) => {
     const { name, value } = event.target;
     this.setState({
       [name]: value,
     });
   };
   ```

### Form

1. Storing passed props in local component state is ***anti-pattern*** in React, just reference the prop values directly. If you store them in state then you ***must*** also implement `componentDidUpdate` so you can update the local cache saved in state when the props update (*i.e. the state updated in parent*), this is just extra unnecessary work though.
2. The `changeInput` handler doesn't consume an `onChange` event nor pass it on to `this.props.changeInput`, but similar to the previous point, just attach `this.props.changeInput` to the elements needing it.
3. The child component that needs the `props.changeInput` callback is the component rendering the inputs, i.e. in your case it seems is the `Personal` component.

   ```
   class Form extends Component {
     render() {
       const {
         address,
         changeInput,
         description,
         email,
         firstName,
         lastName,
         phoneNum,
         submitForm,
         title,
       } = this.props;

       return (
         <form className="cvForm" onSubmit={submitForm}>
           <Personal
             onChange={changeInput} // <-- pass change handler here
             firstName={firstName}
             lastName={lastName}
             title={title}
             address={address}
             phoneNum={phoneNum}
             email={email}
             description={description}
           />

           ...
         </form>
       );
     }
   }
   ```

### Preview

1. All same comments as for `Form` component. Don't locally store the passed props and use the `this.props.changeInput` callback directly. Since this is a preview it likely doesn't need an `onChange` handler.

   ```
   class Preview extends Component {
     render() {
       const {
         firstName,
         lastName,
         title,
         address,
         phoneNum,
         email,
         description
       } = this.props;

       return (
         <div className="cvPreview">
           <div className="gridItem nameItem">
             <h1>
               {title} {firstName} {lastName}
             </h1>
             <h3>Data engineer</h3>
             ... other fields
           </div>
         </div>
       );
     }
   }
   ```

## Demo

[image: Edit react-passing-state-down]

Comment: I have done that. When i console.log the target value it shows the values typed into input boxes. No errors anymore. But I still cannot print them on the right side component (the preview component).
Preview: 
return (
      <div className="cvPreview" onChange={this.props.changeInput}>
          <h1 >
            {firstName} {lastName}
          </h1>
Maybe I am not passing onChange where it should be?

Comment: @jsme That is entirely possible. You were previously passing `props.changeInput` to the form, but it needs to be passed to the component rendering the inputs, I'm assuming it's the `Personal` component that the field values are being passed to. I've updated my answer to call this out specifically and also include a *running* codesandbox demo. Please check the update.

Comment: I did! That was a really helpful solution. Everything is working, finally.

Comment: Accepted! Unfortunately, when I upvote, it says I don't have enough reputation, but it is recorded. So I guess it will show once I collect 4 more rep.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with your `handleInputChange` . `setState` should be a function call.

```
handleInputChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
    });
  };
```

This is how the setState API looks like [React setState](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) . Also i see that your state is dependent on props in `Preview` component.

```
 this.state = {
       firstName: this.props.firstName,
       lastName: this.props.lastName,
       title: this.props.title,
       address: this.props.address,
       phoneNum: this.props.phoneNum,
       email: this.props.email,
       description: this.props.description
     }
```

This is not needed since you are passing the state to your children components as props . Your Children components will always re-render when there is a change in their props ( change in the state of the parent component).

So in your preview component you can now remove the state and have this

```
const {firstName, lastName, title, address, phoneNum, email, description} = this.props;
```

This blog from @danAbramov explains the issues one might face when having their state dependent on props.

[state dependent on props](https://overreacted.io/writing-resilient-components/#principle-1-dont-stop-the-data-flow)